# multidimensional array from json_decode to array(array())

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

Thanks for looking at this question - I'm very new to php and have read tons of posts on arrays but can't seem to find the answer I need.

I have a json string which I decode using `json_decode($string, true)`.  It is nested up to four layers deep and the nested levels will vary from file to file.

I want to build an associative array so that I can get it into mysql eventually.

The section of the decoded file I'm having trouble with is this:

```
[LineItems] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ItemNumber] => 1
                [Category] => Prep Sink with 18"DB
                [SubLineItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [ItemTypeCode] => 0
                                [ItemTypeDescription] => Normal
                                [VendorId] => 55d14674-f295-4f9c-9c37-79f2
                                ... deleted for readability

                                [CustomerSpecificPricings] => Array
                                    (
                                    .... deleted for readablity
                                    )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ItemNumber] => 2
                [Category] => Combi Oven
                [SubLineItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                ....
                                    (
                                    )

                                [ElectricalUtilityGrids] => Array
                                    (
                                    .... 
                                    )
```

While using a foreeach I can get the [LineItems] array to build using:

```
$LineItems=array();

foreach($data['LineItems'] as $lineitems => $lineitem){
    $lineadd=array(
        $ItemNumber=$lineitem['ItemNumber'],
        $Category=$lineitem['Category']
        );
}
```

But when I try to added the nested array:

```
$LineItems=array();
$SubLineItems=array();

foreach($data['LineItems'] as $lineitems => $lineitem){
    $lineadd=array(
        $ItemNumber=$lineitem['ItemNumber'],
        $Category=$lineitem['Category']
        );
        $LineItems[]=$lineadd;
            foreach($data[LineItems]['SubLineItems'] as $sublineitem =>    $sublineitems){
                $sublineadd[]=array(
                $ItemTypeCode=$sublineitem['ItemTypeCode'],
                $ItemTypeDescription=$sublineitem['ItemTypeDescription'],
                $VendorId=$sublineitem['VendorId'],
                ... deleted rest of list for readability
                );
            $SubLineItems[] = $sublineadd;
            }
    }
```

On the nested foreach trying to access SubLineItems I have tried:

```
($lineitem as $sublineitem => $sublineitems), 
($data[SubLineItems] as $sublineitem => $sublineitems), 
($data[LineItem][SubLineItem] as $sublineitem => $sublineitems)
```

among other things to get the LineItems.SubLineItems index passed to the loop...

I have received multiple errors while attempting this... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a suggestion, to maximize the probability to get a useful answer, try to simplify at most data and code you post here, leaving only question sensible data...

Comment: Simplified - thanks for the tip.

Comment: instead try using recursive function which will keep on adding decoded array value to the key. if (is_array($process[$key])) {decode_json($process[$key])}. let me know if u want me to code it for u :)

Comment: @kanchan - a code snippet would be appreciated!  I am not following  ($process[$key]).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using this:

```
$new_array=array();
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($json),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
        $new_array[$key]=$item;        
        }
```

Is there a better solution?